# Gradle Build failed

Tags: java, android, gradle

So I am freaking out right now -

I tried to add the Facebook SDK on my app following a Youtube tutorial. However it did not go to plan. So I deleted the files - I basically un-did them

BUT...

I am getting this error

Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
Warning:Project app: provided dependencies can only be jars. com.android.support:appcompat-v7:aar:22.1.1 is an Android Library.
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72211Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42211Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
Project app: provided dependencies can only be jars. com.android.support:appcompat-v7:aar:22.1.1 is an Android Library.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:prepareDebugDependencies'.

> Dependency Error. See console for details
>   Information:BUILD FAILED
>   Information:Total time: 1.824 secs
>   Information:1 error
>   Information:1 warning
>   Information:See complete output in console

Gradle Console:
Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
WARNING: Project app: provided dependencies can only be jars. com.android.support:appcompat-v7:aar:22.1.1 is an Android Library.
WARNING: Project app: provided dependencies can only be jars. com.android.support:appcompat-v7:aar:22.1.1 is an Android Library.
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72211Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42211Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
Project app: provided dependencies can only be jars. com.android.support:appcompat-v7:aar:22.1.1 is an Android Library.

FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:prepareDebugDependencies'.

  > Dependency Error. See console for details
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 1.824 secs

I have no clue what to do?? :/

Can anyone help, if possible? Can I just save all my code and workings and start again?

Comment: Can you post your `build.gradle` and make sure the formatting looks ok?

Answer (score 0):

try Clean Project.

provided dependencies can only be jars. com.android.support:appcompat-v7:aar

dependencies can only be jars,but you dependencies aar